# Media feature for Windows 7 homepack so I can download Icloud?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I cannot seem to download Media Feature for windows 7 so I can then dowload Icloud?

Comment: run winver.exe and look if you see N in name

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot seem to download Media Feature for windows 7 so I can then
>   download ICloud?

This means you have a K or KN edition of Windows 7.  You need to download [KB968211](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16546) to solve your first problem

> It says Icloud is not enabled??

Your second problem is a setting issue

> ### You see “iCloud Photos is not enabled,”
>
> > **If you’re signed in to iCloud for Windows but you see “iCloud Photos
> >     is not enabled,” check your settings.**
>
> - Open iCloud for Windows.
> - Select Photos.
> - Next to Photos, click Options.
> - Select My Photo Stream. And if you want to choose photos and videos to share with friends, select iCloud Photo Sharing.
> - Click OK > Apply.

Source: [I'm signed in to iCloud for Windows, but a message in Photos says I'm not](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204914)